# Is the phrase professor emerita grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar-choice, gender

Since professor has masculine gender, one may think that the phrase should be *professor emeritus*, regardless of the gender of the person referred to. Is the use of *emerita* simply a case of grammatical ignorance?

Answer (score 13):

In theory, the feminine of *professor* would be [*profestrix*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/183/406). However, this is a rather awkward formation, and isn't attested classically—the use of *-trix* on a dental-stem noun is incredibly rare in any period.

So most often, in my experience at least, the word *professor* is used for both the masculine and the feminine. If the professor is female, the noun is feminine, and thus takes a first-declension adjective like *emerita*. (For a Classical precedent, see gender-neutral third-declension nouns like *homo* and *canis*.)

Comment: By that logic could a female member of the Homo Erectus genus be referred to as a Homo Erecta?

Comment: @Persistence Scientific names generally don't change their form, but in Latin that wouldn't be incorrect: see [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2597/406) for some examples of *homo* used for a woman.

Comment: @Persistence It would be nice to have a separate question about that so people could find the answer easily.

Comment: One example I have not seldom heard is *nestrix*. Oh, and *rectrix* is not uncommon.

Answer (score 8):

To supplement the answer by Draconis, *professor* is what's called a common gender noun, at least in modern usage.
This means that the grammatical gender is not fixed, but depends on the semantic gender.
When referring to a male professor, *professor* is masculine, and feminine when referring to female.
I would consider it impolite in today's world to use *professor* as purely masculine word for professors of all genders.

The form *professor emerita* is correct.
While there is the feminine option *profestrix emerita*, this form is not really used.
The word *profestrix* is the Latin equivalent of the French *professeure*, but appears to be far less common.

Feminine forms such as *doctrix* and *lectrix* [have been used](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/831/79) and are in no way inappropriate for female academicians.
However, it appears to be more common to use the (seemingly) masculine words *doctor*, *lector*, and *professor* instead.

Comment: It seems women have been teaching [since the origin of mediaeval universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_women%27s_education). It would be interesting to find some written evidence of their titles. I had a go but failed. Maybe you are a better searcher than me.

Comment: @luchonacho I edited my answer a bit. [This old question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/831/79) has an example which might be in the spirit of what you are looking for. I would be interested to see follow-up questions on the topic, though.

Comment: "I would consider it impolite in today's world to use professor as purely masculine word for professors of all genders." That is surely English specific. But can perhaps be extended to Latin.

Comment: @VladimirF That is certainly a matter of opinion, and I was very conscious about prefacing it with "I would consider". But since Latin does not force *professor* to be exclusively masculine, I would find it inappropriate to treat it as exclusively masculine in this day and age. Different languages and different people might come to other conclusions.

Comment: @luchonacho [*magistra*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmagistra) is classically attested. Considering that in medieval universities *magister* was the title for the highest teachers, that might be a better route to go.

Comment: Interesting. The question you linked suggests the "first ever professor", which it at odds with the link i provided.

Answer (score 4):

We normally distinguish between nouns of “common gender”, which can be used either as masculine or as feminine depending on the sex of the person or animal in question, and “epicene nouns", which have a fixed gender, but can refer to creatures of either sex. If “professor” is treated as epicene, then one would have to say “professor emeritus” for a person of either sex, at least in (Neo-)Latin.

In English there are no gendered forms for adjectives, so there is no reason not to say “emeritus professor” in reference to a woman in an English context.

In Germany there has been a heated debate over whether a female professor should be styled “Professor” or “Professorin”. In lecture lists of German universities you now normally find just “Prof.” - one way to dodge the question.