# How does one show that a person or thing is the performer of an action?

Tags: classical-latin, derivation

I've noticed that many Latin verbs can be turned into nouns (like the English *do* and *doer*). But, what's the process of this in Latin? I can find some terms in dictionaries, but most don't seem to have entries for such a thing.

Comment: Root of the 4th principal part of the verb (root of participle, so-to-speak) followed by _-or_ (-rix for feminine). Facere --> factus --> **factor** (factrix); dare --> datus --> **dator**. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You might be interested in [this old question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/178/79).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming we're in a codified state (from the tags), there are two primary ways. The first is use the present participle as a substantive. E.g. Cic. [*Div*. 68.141](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0042%3Abook%3D2%3Asection%3D141) (from [G-L § 437](https://books.google.com/books?id=jo1iAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA285#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

> Nihil est magnum somnianti
>
> Nothing is great to a dreamer (= to one dreaming)

Be careful, though, because in the ablative singular the ending is an *e* instead of an *i* when it's used this way. This works for both the masculine and feminine.

The other way is to take the fourth principal part (i.e. either the perfect passive participal or the supine*, drop the ending, and add *or* to it. For example, take the word *servo*, *servare*, "to save." The fourth principal part is *servatus*, which would give is *servator*, "savior." The feminine form would be *servatrix*. For neuter nouns, the ending is -trum, which is how we get words like *rostrum* (from *rodere*).

Comment: +1. Since OP specified "person or thing", you might mention neuter *-rum* also.

Comment: @Draconis Done.

Comment: Thanks! So lover would be amator/amatrix, speaker as dicitor/dicitrix, and hater would become irator/iratrix?

Comment: @MiddleSchoolHistorian The fourth principal part of *dicere* is *dictus*, but yeah, you have the principle down.