# A plausible technical term for 'boiler'

Tags: vocabulary, technology

I'm looking for a word for 'boiler' as in the phrase 'the ship's  boiler nearly burst', but I can't think of anything remotely suitable.

Perhaps there is something obvious that I can't bring to mind? Can anyone help?

Comment: Surely this word must already exist. Latin texts describing steam ships must be out there somewhere.

Comment: @C. M. Weimer I tend to agree, but am blessed if I can find much. _Vaporella_, which I use for steam-launch, turns out to be a steam-iron in Italian, but 40 years ago my usage gained approval from a senior Latin don. Now, having settled for _vaporatorium_, I see that it is in widespread use as the modern place for supplying or using smoking substitutes. It's impossible to win!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of boiler is also known as a steam generator, and direct translations from relevant words in other languages are mostly "steam generator" or "steam pot".
One could take for example the Italian expression "generatore di vapore" and adapt to Latin.
The result, *generator/generatrum vaporis*, should be easily understood and descriptive.
I find the [neuter agent noun derivative](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/178/79) most suitable here, but some might prefer the masculine.

However, I would prefer to start with the verb [*vaporare*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2062090), which means just the kind of things a boiler would do: emit steam, glow, heat…
Therefore my suggestion is ***vaporatrum***.
This is admittedly new coinage to the best of my knowledge, but I find the word descriptive, neat, and understandable.

Comment: Thank you! for removing my mental block. The boiler in this case (from the comic novel 'Three Men In A Boat', or _Tres Viri in Scapha_) drives a 19thC steam-launch, which I have been translating as _vaporella_. I think I'll settle for _vaporatorium_.

Comment: @TomCotton You are welcome! *Vaporatorium* sounds good, too.

Answer (score 11):

The classical author Vitruvius was familiar with a basic steam turbine, which he describes in [*De architectura I.VI.2*](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~harsch/Chronologia/Lsante01/Vitruvius/vit_ar01.html) thus:

> Fiunt enim aeoli pilae aereae cavae, - hae habent punctum angustissimum - quae aqua infunduntur conlocanturque ad ignem; et antequam calescant, non habent ullum spiritum, simul autem ut fervere coeperint, efficiunt ad ignem vehementem flatum.

You could follow him in using *aeoli pila*.

Comment: Interesting. In modern English "[aeolipile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeolipile)" seems to refer to a specific design of steam engine.

Comment: @sumelic A couple paragraphs in it says: _"Pre-dating Heron's writings, a device called an aeolipile was described in the 1st century BC by Vitruvi in his treatise De architectura; however, it is unclear if it is the same device or a predecessor, as he does not mention rotating parts."_

Answer (score 11):

You've probably already checked here, but *Smith's Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary* offers ***fornax vaporifer*** as a "furnace emitting steam", citing Statius' *Silvae* [1.3.45](https://books.google.com/books?id=PU_rxafMU4sC&pg=PA64&dq=vaporiferis):

> An quae graminea suscepta crepidine fumant
> balnea et impositum ripis algentibus ignem,
> quaque **vaporiferis** iunctus **fornacibus** amnis
> ridet anhelantes vicino flumina Nymphas?
>
> Or [shall I sing] of the steaming baths taken up by their [the silent woods'] grassy ledge and fire imposed on chilly banks, where the river linked to a **vaporous furnace** laughs at the Nymphs as they pant, though the stream be hard by?
>
> <sup>Translation: D.R. Shackleton Bailey, Loeb's Classical Library.</sup>

That's, er, not exactly an allusion to a steam engine. Maybe it's supposed to make the reader think of the kind of boiler used to heat a Roman bath. If so, that's not a bad classical precedent to start from. I don't know a lot about either, but I understand both the Roman boiler at a *therma* and the boiler for a steam engine to work on the same principle: a vessel containing water is exposed to fire, the water turns to steam, a pipe leads the steam up to some form of heat exchanger where the heat does something useful, and a pipe returns the resulting cold water back down to the boiler.

Some quick googling suggests that my guess about how the heat was transferred in a Roman bath might be wrong: some sources suggest that they heated [hypocausts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocaust) with air or smoke rather than by steam turning to water. But I'm not sure. [This extraordinary commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=IGhPU5TThAAC&pg=PA140&dq=%22tenuem%20volvunt%20hypocausta%20vaporem%22) on Vitrivius's explanation of how the baths were heated explains more, and it mentions many ancient words for the boiler or closely related things, including **vaporarium**, **caldarium vas**, **miliarium**, and **fornacula**. Have a look; it may give you a new idea.

Anyway, I was trying to follow C.M. Weimer's [suggestion](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/a-plausible-technical-term-for-boiler#comment9685_4744) to see what's been written in Latin about steam ships.

Could you use ***vaporifer*** substantively? [Forcellini](http://www.linguax.com/lexica/forc.php?searchedLG=vaporifer) defines *vaporifer* as an adjective meaning *vaporem et calorem emittens* and gives a few more classical citations. The *calorem* gives me some hope. Nothing about steam engines there, but steam engines were just getting started in Forcellini's time. A quick look at [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=vaporifer&tbm=bks), though, suggests that a few people have invented the word *vaporifer* to mean various things, but none for steam boilers.

[Here is an article](https://books.google.com/books?id=WG7RLyV6ongC&pg=PA708&dq=vaporario) explaining how steamboats work in a four-language version of Comenius's *Orbis Pictus* updated by J.G. Gailer in 1842. It says:

> Quae vis ut efficiatur, ignis sub **aheno vaporario** perpetuo alendus est.
>
> The fire must in order to produce this power be continually kept up under the **steam boiler**.
>
> <sup>Translation: J.G. Gailer, apparently a native speaker of German.</sup>

So, it appears that ***ahenum vaporarium*** has one precedent specifically for a steam boiler on a steam ship—in a children's book. This is the only instance I found. I can't tell if the substantive is *ahenum* modified by *vaporarium* or the other way around. Either way, *ahenum,* suggesting copper, seems unnecessarily narrow. [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=vaporarium) reveals that ***vaporarium*** as a substantive by itself has other established meanings, most notably a greenhouse (in botanical Latin) and (I think) a sauna. Classically, the *vaporarium* seems to be the pipe carrying steam to the hypocaust (hey, maybe my first guess was right). Cicero uses it in *Q. fr.* [3.1.2](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust2012&getid=0&query=Cic.%20Q.%20fr.%203.1.2).

Comment: Thank you. I did in fact consider _cisterna vaporifer_, which might be a reasonable physical description of a ship's boiler, but have settled for _vaporatorium_ as better fitting into both context and translation (but see also my comment beneath the original question!). [The 'Copious & Critical' is indeed a useful source of suggestions in cases like this, and, unsurprisingly, often gives matches for 19thC English better than more modern works.]

Comment: Note that in the Mass Effect community (Mass Effect is a sci-fi video game), there is a seedy magazine aimed at xenophiles called Fornax (named after the constellation with the same name, most likely). This probably won't confuse people who haven't played the game, but it's just something to keep in mind when choosing words. Unfortunate implications and all that.

Answer (score 9):

A suitable word in Spanish is *caldera*, which sounded pretty Latin to me. So looking at L&S I finally converged to [**caldaria**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaldarius). One of its meanings is:

> A pot for boiling

Even if you were not looking for a word for *pot*, I think the analogy remains valid.

Comment: In English **caldera** is the word for the collapsed volcano that destroyed Santorini.  Overkill for a little steam launch.

Answer (score 7):

A [***caminus***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaminus) (from Greek κάμινος) is a furnace, so another possibility is a *caminus vaporalis*.