# Is there a diminutive form for agent nouns?

Tags: morphology, derivation, noun, diminutive, agent

I recently read a joke about the use of Latin -tor and -trix nouns in modern English. The punchline was that "trix is for kids".

This got me wondering: Is there a way to make diminutives from agent nouns?

For example, knowing that the diminutive form of *rex* is *regulus*, the diminutive form of *saltatrix* might conceivably be *saltatrigula*, although I admit it sounds a bit clunky, and it could be completely wrong.

I have no idea what the masculine equivalent would be, however. *Saltatorulus* sounds much more wrong than *saltatrigula*.

Are there any existing diminutives of agent (-tor/-trix) nouns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are agent nouns for all genders.
For example, *saltare* gives rise to *saltator*, *saltatrix*, and *saltatrum*.
For more details, see [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/178/79).

The stem is revealed by the genitive form.
For my three examples they are *saltator-* (third conjugation), *saltatric-* (third), and *saltatr-* (second).
(The stem of *rex* is *reg-*, so it has a *g* instead of a *c*.)
If you want to use the usual *-ulus/-ula/-ulum* for diminutives, it would have to be attached to these stems.
So the natural guesses would be *saltatorulus*, *saltatricula*, and *saltatrulum*.

Then it remains to check whether such diminutives are actually in use.
The word [*saltatricula*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsaltatricula) is post-classical but attested.
The given translation is, unsurprisingly, "little dancing girl".
For another similar example, [*cicatricula*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcicatricula) is a diminutive of *cicatrix*, and also *nutricula* comes from *nutrix*.
These make a decent case for diminutives of words ending in *-trix*, including feminine agents.

I found no examples of *-torulus* (apart from the word *torulus*, a small *torus*).
A different kind of diminutive suffix might work, and *-torculus* sounds more natural to me.
Indeed, it does exist: [*amatorculus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Damatorculus).
I found no other examples though, so perhaps there is another way or this just is so rare.
If you need a diminutive of a masculine agent, I suggest *-torculus*.

I found no examples of *-trulum* or *-trellum*.
They both sound reasonable to me so I would go with either of them, but I have not managed to find any examples of such words in a dictionary.

So, the three little dancers should probably be *saltatorculus*, *saltatricula*, and *saltatrulum* or *saltatrellum*.
Such diminutives are rarely pre-existing words, but diminutives and agents are productive in Latin and especially in proper context such words are easily understandable.

Comment: If there are/were any neuter diminutives old enough to take part in the relevant sound changes, it would probably have ended up as _-tellum_. No idea if there are any of those either, though.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! And for pointing out the neuter form, which had slipped my mind entirely.

Comment: Wells, there's always the good old "saltatrix parva" :P

Answer (score 9):

The example that I'm familiar with is *meretricula*, found in, e.g., Plautus, *Rudens* 62-63:

> ipse hinc ilico
>   conscendit navem, avehit meretriculas.

Answer (score 6):

> Are there any existing diminutives of agent (-tor/-trix) nouns?

Yes, though the rarest.

Examples for -trix have been already mentioned by @Joonas and @cnread: *nutricula, meretricula*...

I'd like to add an example for an adjective derived from a -tor word: *punctatoriola*, as the diminutive of *punctatorius* from *punctator*: the reference is *Festi Fragm. e Cod. Farn.*:

"punctatoriolas levis pugnas appellat Cato in ea, quam dixit de re Histriae militari".

---

If you'd like to know some good sources addressing the topic, you might be interested in:

- [Latin Diminutives: A Semantic Study](https://books.google.it/books?id=78DKWQrYLocC&q=Latin%20Diminutives:%20A%20Semantic%20Study&dq=Latin%20Diminutives:%20A%20Semantic%20Study&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_7OyP9YjnAhVs7aYKHZdQBJYQ6AEILDAA), by Jens S. Th Hanssen, 1952;
- The article [Latin Diminutives in -Ello/A- and -Illo/A- A Study in Diminutive Formation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/522000?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents), by George Kleppinger Strodach, 1933.

Comment: That's not quite the same though, is it? The agent noun itself isn't being made into a diminutive. Instead the derived adjective punctatorius is. Diminutives from adjectives aren't so uncommon (whereas, apparently, diminutives of masculine agent nouns are.)

Comment: @cnread I agree with you; however, I've reported the hypothesis of  Hanssen, who says that Cato may have used there the same word *punctator https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhNKf.png

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Why is it _nutric**o**la_ (sounds like a healthy soda, btw) but _metetric**u**la_? 2. What does it mean when you use the diminutive form of an adjective? Is it like prexifing an adjective in English with "a little"?

Comment: @Dhi Because obviously I've miswritten XD Thanks, it's nutricula, otherwise yeah it would be a healthy soda (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX0SQ.png), or a jellyfish.  There are in Latin (also in Italian) diminutives of adjectives - not for all adjectives though. In English they are usually rendered as you write, by prefixing (a little, a bit, quite), or by using word such *teeny, weeny*...

Comment: *barcarole* (a kind of song), if from *barca* (a kind of ship, from Egy *bar*) would exhibit ***o*** anyway. Wonder if *-ca* is also diminutive, cp Ger *-chen, -ken*, Pol *-ska* (not to be confused with Slavic fem. suf. *-ka*?).

Comment: @vectory that's a really interesting question! Here (https://www.etimo.it/?term=barca) are some hypothesis on the etymo; to me makes sense it can be a diminutive if derived from Egy *bar* and Greek *bar-is* (a cargo boat). Instead, if we think about Celtic *bar* (tree branch) that's maybe more difficult XD

Comment: I don't see that the bit of Hanssen that you link to contradicts me (hence, I don't understand the 'however' in your comment). H. says merely that punctator is a word that Cato may well have used; and that punctariola, which is what actually appears in the mss, could therefore be haplography for punctatoriola instead of a corruption of pugnariola. This backs up what I said about the word: = punctatorius (adj. < punctator + ius) + ola. (I note, though, that while OLD accepts that punctatoriola is the correct word, it gives the etym. as punctus + torius + ola; in any case, diminutive of an adj.)

Comment: @cnread yeah, I agree with you.