# Nomen agentis of 'Quaerere'

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

Everybody knows words like Terminator, Navigator, Laudator, ...
For verbs from the a conjugation is seems pretty simple to build the Nomen Agentis, what about words like 'Quaerere'?

I thought about that as I was looking for a name for a latin app I'm developing where you can search forms with (that's why quaerere came to mind).
I wanted to make a cool word out of that and I found 'Quaetor'. I'll take that, but I still wonder, if that word could even exist?

I've read that there are many possibilities like using parts of the ppp like in 'regere -> rectus -> rex' or 'vincere -> victus -> vixtrix' and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: *Rex* is different, but you will have seen the actual agentive noun: *rector*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These agent names are typically derived from the past participle stem.
For *quarere* the participle stem is *quaesit-*, so we should expect *quaesitor*.
And indeed, [*quaesitor* is an attested word](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DQ%3Aentry+group%3D3%3Aentry%3Dquaesitor) meaning "seeker, searcher, investigator", and such.

There is also a contracted form (which at least L&S says is a contraction of *quaesitor*): [the title *quaestor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DQ%3Aentry+group%3D3%3Aentry%3Dquaestor).

With the typical derivation in *-or*, you would get *rector* and *victor* from *regere* and *vincere*, respectively, and these words are indeed real.

[There is a separate question on feminine and neuter versions of *-or*.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/178/79)